# How to catch 404 error in webview of android

Tags: android

To catch error in webview, I used onReceivedError function. But it is not ok for 404 error. How should I do?
Thanks

Comment: do you mean 404. page not found error ?

Comment: yes.i mean "page not found" error

Comment: that you can achieve from getResponseCode() method

Comment: Ok I will try with it.Thanks, Lucifer.

Comment: Please Lucifer, how will I use getResponseCode() for default url (such as google).Is it need to use HttpUrlConnection for google? I don't know how to get response code.Please guide me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

Comment: Elitist close. Clearly the person's native language is NOT english, there was no need to close for the reason provided, @skjaidev and others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
    if(errorCode == WebViewClient.ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
        // your code

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not for http 404, this handle local file not found (url like file://blahblahblah)